# Replace a part of a substring in a column using a dict

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, replace

In pyspark, I have a dataframe with 3 columns and I want to replace part of a column value with a value from a dictionary. df.replace will replace *only* if the entire column value is part of the dictionary, but I want to replace the value from a part of the column value. For instance:

```
id = [("val1","01-JAN-2021","01-MAR-2021"),
      ("val2","02-JUL-2021","01-AUG-2022"),
      ("val3","02-JUL-2021",None)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(id,["id","start_date","end_date"])
df = df.replace(date_dict, subset = ["start_date", "end_date"])
```

Dictionary is:

```
date_dict = {"JAN": "Jan",
          "FEB" : "Feb",
          "MAR" : "Mar",
          "APR" : "Apr",
          "MAY" : "May",
          "JUN" : "Jun",
          "JUL" : "Jul",
          "AUG" : "Aug",
          "SEP" : "Sep",
          "OCT" : "Oct",
          "NOV" : "Nov",
          "DEC" : "Dec"}
```

I tried the below:

```
df = df.replace(date_dict, subset = ["start_date", "end_date"])
```

but it would not replace as the column values are say '01-JUN-2020' vs just "JUN". Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have to do a replace ? Why not just convert everything to upper case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid in PySpark there's no implemented function that replace substrings of string columns according to a defined dictionary; you probably need to resort to tricks.

In this case for instance, you can:

- substitute hyphens (`-`) with empty spaces ( ) thanks to [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html)
- use the [`initcap`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.initcap.html) function to make all words in a sentence start with a capital letter
- substitute back empty spaces ( ) with hyphens (`-`) to rebuild the original date structure

#### Code

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df\
  .withColumn('start_date', F.regexp_replace(F.initcap(F.regexp_replace('start_date', '-', ' ')), ' ', '-'))\
  .withColumn('end_date', F.regexp_replace(F.initcap(F.regexp_replace('end_date', '-', ' ')), ' ', '-'))

df.show()

+----+-----------+-----------+
|  id| start_date|   end_date|
+----+-----------+-----------+
|val1|01-Jan-2021|01-Mar-2021|
|val2|02-Jul-2021|01-Aug-2022|
|val3|02-Jul-2021|       null|
+----+-----------+-----------+
```